# Simple Kendo UI button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

For an asp.net mvc4 website, Is there a way to use *Kendo UI* for a simple button? This is not a mobile app. But Kendo UI does not appear to have regular button object like `Html.Kendo().Button...` It's not there.

This is what I have now

```
<input type="submit" value="Run Calculation" />
```

I want to use Kendo UI button instead.

```
@(Html.Kendo().MobileButton()
    .Name("textButton")
    .HtmlAttributes( new {type = "button"} )        
)
```

But its not rendering at all.

Comment: Why you are using mobile button? is it mobile app? nowhere you talk about it. if NO it isn't mobile app then:  `@(Html.Kendo().Button().Name("textButton").HtmlAttributes( new {type = "button"} ).Content("Text button"))` should work ok.

Comment: Hi Iman.. have you tried the code? Html.Kendo().Button() is not there.. I will try it but I doubt it will work. This is not a mobile app. This is regular website.

Comment: Iman. what you listed is from Kendo ui website.. I tried it .. it does not work.

Comment: yes there is, look at this [`Button / Basic usage
 -> ASP.NET MVC -> index.cshtml`](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/button/index.html). and as you can see button widget is flaged _new_ it means you should have latest version, I think your version hasn't it.

Comment: Iman.. thanks for feedback.. have you tried it? I just got the latest version like 2 days ago. This code on their site does not work.

Comment: The button is there since Q3 2013... Are you sure that you are using the latest version of the server side wrapper? **What is the exact version number of your Kendo.MVC.dll**?

Comment: you are welcome, No I don't try it, because I work with kendo ui instead  of server side wrappers(I don't believe on them). I think there maybe other reason it don't work, e.g you don't link to kendo javascripts ,...

Comment: Iman.. I just created a brand new VS2012 MVC project with latest from kendo ui and it does not have @Html.Kendo().Button() ...

Comment: Iman.. I don't think I need to link to any kendo javascript.. it sould just work like many other controls that I have used.

Comment: nemesv, here are is the version related information, RunTime Version =v4.0.30319 , Version = 2013.2.918.340

Comment: nemesv, I am using the latest version of kendo ui framework.

Comment: The 2013.2 918 is **not the latest version** it is from Sep 18, 2013. You need to use at least **2013.3 1119** form Nov 20, 2013... It actual latest version is **2013.3 1324** from Jan 28, 2014.

Comment: ok it means it is 2012, Q2 ->`2013.2.*.*` not Q3 because it then should be like `2013.3.*.*`

Comment: nemesv, I just tried to update kendo ui framework from my visual studio and it succedded with the version number that I just listed. how would i upgrade?

Comment: I don't know how the VS updarade works so you need to login the Telerik.com  with your Telerik accound and download the latest server side wrappers from there...

Comment: nemesv, I don't have the paid version of telerik. May be that is the issue then.

Comment: I think you can use trial version and there should not be any problem to use it for a while. and second, when you update telerik's kendo mvc it will give you an option to upgrade the opened project to latest version of kendo.

Comment: Iman, I just upgraded it within visual studio, The upgrade Wizard Log indicates that the upgrade was successful. But still no luck. My trial account expired few months ago.

Comment: So you should buy a licence from great telerik company, or maybe you can create new account and try new 2013 Q3 for some days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can not access `Html.Kendo().Button()` it means your kendo ui mvc version is not `2013 Q3` or later.

the new code should be like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
.Name("textButton")
.HtmlAttributes( new {type = "button"} )
.Content("Text button"))
```

Demo: [`Button / Basic usage -> ASP.NET MVC -> index.cshtml`](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/button/index.html)

Comment: Iman, when you get a chance, please try it at your end, and if you are successful, I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner I have tested with `2013.2.918.340` and `2013.3.1127.440` I had not `Html.Kendo().Button()` in first one but in the second one after upgrading `Kendo.Mvc.dll` to `2013.3.1127.440` and restarting VS I have access to  `Html.Kendo().Button()`.

Comment: I just have both version `2013.2.918.340` and `2013.3.1127.440` of `Kendo.Mvc.dll`. first create my project with `2013.2.918.340` test it, and then remove `Kendo.Mvc.dll` from References and add `2013.3.1127.440` and restart VS.

Comment: Iman, I was able to download the latest kendo ui as a trial version and get the button to work. Thanks for your help.